# Ignore a logger category in another logger category in jboss 6.4

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6, jboss-logging

There are  2 log file which are pointed by a category in standalone.xml using logging feature in jboss eap 6.4.
We want to skip the log of category="com.java.code.ABCD" that is printing in category="com.java.code".

Appreciate your help.

Please find below the sample code in my standalone.xml file

```
<logging-profile name="projectA">
<size-rotating-file-handler name="ABCD">
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="/ABCD/application.log" />
    <rotate-size value="10096K" />
    <max-backup-index value="10" />
    <append value="true" />
</size-rotating-file-handler>
<size-rotating-file-handler name="common">
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="/common/common.log" />
    <rotate-size value="10096K" />
    <max-backup-index value="10" />
    <append value="true" />
</size-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="com.java.code">
    <level name="INFO" />
    <handlers>
        <handler name="common" />
    </handlers>
</logger>
<logger category="com.java.code.ABCD">
    <level name="DEBUG" />
    <handlers>
        <handler name="ABCD" />
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "skip"? Do you not any any log messages printed that are from `com.java.code.ABCD`?

Comment: Np, i got it resolved by using parameter (use-parent-handlers="false") on logger category tag.